# Grid view i need to create

Tags: flutter, user-interface, gridview

[image]

i Just need to create some thing like this and it's scrollable to horizontal there is another set this available when we scroll to right i just did like this but not worked i hope i did something that's not right

```
body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      ImageSlideshow(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: mHeight * 0.5,
        initialPage: 0,
        indicatorColor: Colors.grey,
        indicatorBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        autoPlayInterval: 1500,
        isLoop: true,
        children: [
          Image.network(
            'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597734187998-e1931acfe2ed?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8bWFzamlkfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&w=1000&q=80',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          Image.network(
            'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTPXlJihD-aeeSlMpTx8NV2rwkPzqw5UANQLHfCv0nmC0sQkCRkrSe6fXHSqjV2wm8NgA8&usqp=CAU',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      MSalahTime(mHeight: mHeight),
      Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      )
      Expanded(
        child: GridView.count(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: List<Widget>.generate(
            6,
            (counter) => Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Container(
                width: mWidth * 0.3,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide `crossAxisCount:n`, based on your ui n will be 3. But it will 2 being `Axis.horizontal`

```dart
child: GridView.count(
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
```

More about using [`GridView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you need to put your `gridview` inside the `pageview` so you can swipe right or left with page indicator

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: GridViewPage(),
    );
  }
}

class GridViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const GridViewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GridViewPage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<GridViewPage> {
  List<String> gridItems = [
    "item 1",
    "item 2",
    "item 3",
    "item 4",
    "item 5",
    "item 6",
    "item 7",
    "item 8",
    "item 9",
    "item 10",
    "item 1",
    "item 12"
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xFFE6E6E6),
            ),
            child: PageView.builder(
              // controller: _controller,
              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: (gridItems.length / 6).ceil(),
              itemBuilder: (context, i) => GridView.builder(
                // padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                physics: const ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 3,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                  childAspectRatio: 4 / 1.5,
                ),
                itemCount: 6,
                primary: false,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 50,
                    child: Image.network(
                        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/04/14/12/monitor-1307227__340.jpg"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```